# Is it possible to create a ClearCase VOB on a local disk?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I'm working with ClearCase 8 to test integration with my company's software, and I will be using the client and server software on the same machine, so I don't need the test VOBs I create to be accessible over the network.  I'm trying to create a VOB on a local disk, rather than a network share, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it, if it is even possible.

First, I tried just using a regular path, e.g.:

```
cleartool mkvob -tag \vobFoo C:\Users\Public\cc_vobs\vobFoo.vbs
cleartool: Error: storage directory must be in UNC style (e.g. \\host\share\...)
```

After finding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787203/unc-path-to-a-folder-on-my-local-computer), my next attempt was this:

```
cleartool mkvob -tag \vobFoo \\localhost\c$\Users\Public\cc_vobs\vobFoo.vbs
cleartool: Error: Attempt to get location information on "\\localhost\c$\Users\Public\cc_vobs\vobFoo.vbs" failed: Invalid argument.
```

I checked - typing `\\localhost\c$\Users` into the "Run..." menu does bring up the proper folder in Windows Explorer, so I don't think it's an issue with the loopback adapter.

I did find some references to the error message [here](http://ejostrander.com/cc_errors.html#ERROR24) and [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/vob-admin.htm), but neither seems applicable to my situation (I'm not using UNIX and ClearCase Doctor doesn't give me the relevant error message)

Even after setting up a Windows share, this also failed:

```
cleartool mkvob -tag \vobFoo \\localhost\cc_vobs\vobFoo.vbs
cleartool: Error: Attempt to get location information on "\\localhost\cc_vobs\vobFoo.vbs" failed: Invalid argument.
```

The only way I could get the command to go through was to use the network host name with the share:

```
cleartool mkvob -tag \vobFoo \\hostname\cc_vobs\vobFoo.vbs
```

Is it simply not possible to setup a VOB in a local storage location like I'm trying to do?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm that your UNC path cannot use localhost,  but must start with the host name.

The reason is that the Vob storage path must be *globally* accessible, ie accessible from any computer (and localhost makes sense only from one computer).

The [`cleartool mkvob`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkvob.htm) man page includes:

> Windows—vob-storage-pname must be a UNC name.

[UNC (Uniform Naming Convention)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention):

> The Microsoft Windows UNC, short for Universal Naming Convention or Uniform Naming Convention, specifies a common syntax to describe the location of a network resource, such as a shared file, directory, or printer. The UNC syntax for Windows systems has the generic form:

```
\\ComputerName\SharedFolder\Resource
```

> Microsoft often refers to this as a "network path".

---

One way for you to have a local path (without having to define a share) is to use the `-stgloc` parameter, referring to the name of a pre-defined storage location (instead of `-host -hpath -gpath` arguments)

See [`cleartool mkstgloc`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkstgloc.htm) (which defines storage locations for Vobs or Views).
You can use a local path there.

> In many cases, ClearCase heuristically derives appropriate accessibility information from the `stgloc-pname` argument.
>   In cases where there is no file system connectivity between the server storage location and its clients, ClearCase derives the host name and host-local path, but because no meaningful global path can be derived, you must specify `-ngpath` to unset the global path information.
>
> To create a server storage location for snapshot views or for VOBs intended to be accessed only through snapshot views, use these options:

- `-host -hpath -gpath` when there is file system connectivity between the server storage location host and its clients.
- `-ngpath -host -hpath` when there is no file system connectivity between the server storage location host and its clients.

So be careful if you do this (`-ngpath` option): **your Vob won't be accessible through dynamic views, only snapshot views**.

Comment: It makes sense, I guess.  I suppose with proper permissions on the share it shouldn't be a problem in my case.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a link to IBM documentation that would confirm this? :)

Comment: @Kevin I  will, in a few hours, it is 3am here, I am on my phone, and I need to get back to sleep.