# Save file using a dynamic path

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to save a file. Here the path is static.

```
Sub savefile()

Dim strpath As String
Dim fry As String
Dim mth As String
Dim yr As String

yr = Year(Now)
mth = MonthName(Month(Now))
fry = Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Date, 11)

Filename = "D:\Users\Desktop\ docs\" & yr & " " & "Week Of" & " " & mth & " " & fry & ".jpg"

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (Filename)

End Sub
```

How to replace this static or hardcode with a dynamic path?

Comment: In that case, you may have to ask the user, the path to save the file.

Comment: But how to write the code behind?

Comment: would whis work for you?  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show filename

Comment: Are you trying to save  a workbook as a JPG? This cannot work. Please tell what your actual goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Try below sub

```
Sub SaveFileAs()
Dim strpath As String
Dim fry As String
Dim mth As String
Dim yr As String

    yr = Year(Now)
    mth = MonthName(Month(Now))
    fry = Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Date, 11)

    Filename = yr & " " & "Week Of" & " " & mth & " " & fry

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show (Filename)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you have done with the year, you can allow your user to input data for the path into a variable that is a string and then use & to put the entire path togheter.

example:

```
Sub savefile()

Dim strpath As String
Dim fry As String
Dim mth As String
Dim yr As String
Dim path As String

yr = Year(Now)
mth = MonthName(Month(Now))
fry = Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Date, 11)    

Filename = yr & " " & "Week Of" & " " & mth & " " & fry & ".jpg"
Path = Application.DefaultFilePath & yr & " " & "Week Of" & " " & mth & " " & fry & ".jpg"

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show (Filename)
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (Path)


End Sub
```

If you want your user to input the path directly you can use the `application.dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show (Filename)`

If you want the program to save all the files in a predefined path that can altho change depending on the structure of the computer you are using you could use the `Application.DefaultFilePath` that would save to documents in my case, depending on which folder the user has set up as it's default savefile path it will save there.

NOTE: the default saving location can be changed and it will be where Excel saves files by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you share the same network drive the path should be stated as an [UNC Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787203/unc-path-to-a-folder-on-my-local-computer), for example: (`\\?\C:\my_dir`).

[To find the UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482825/find-unc-path-of-a-network-drive), use the cmd.exe (command prompt) and write net use.