NLog.Web.AspNetCore 5.3.12 raises System.UriFormatException with <TargetFramework> net9.0
FYI to NLog devos:
I have a VS 2022 ASP.NET Core solution that works under .NET 8.0. I updated the TargetFramework to net9.0 and everything works normally. Then I updated all of the NLog.* packages to latest (including NLog.Web.AspNetCore to 5.3.14) and the app broke.
On launch I get a System.UriFormatException from this code:
logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup()
             .LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();

I troubleshot by going through different package versions and in the end it turned out the breakage happens in taking NLog.Web.AspNetCore from 5.3.11 to 5.3.12.
For now I'm good, as I can stick with 5.3.11, but be aware that there's something latent here you'll need to address.
UPDATE: added nlog-internal.txt content generated by 5.3.12, as requested by @RolfKristensen, below the stack trace. When I back down to 5.3.11, the similar output doesn't end where it does in .12:
2024-11-20 15:41:38.5470 Debug Skip loading NLogLoggingConfiguration from empty config section: NLog
2024-11-20 15:41:38.5834 Info Loading NLog config from XML file: Z:\rwells\very\special\NLog.config
...normal loading proceeds...

In .11 it seems that after NLog gives up on the seemingly hostname-less UNC it proceeds with Z:, which is the drive letter mapped to a UNC where my files are located.
Perhaps there was some change/regression in LoggingConfigurationFileLoader relative to UNC- and mapped-drive-handling from .11 to .12?
UPDATE 2 (2024.11.21): see uri-hacking.ps1 and its output, below everything else.
Cheers,
Richard
Stack Trace
System.UriFormatException  
HResult=0x80131537  
Message=Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.  
Source=System.Private.Uri  

StackTrace:  
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)  
at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)  
at System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)  
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)  
at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri)  
at NLog.Internal.Fakeables.AppEnvironmentWrapper.LoadXmlFile(String path)  
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.CreateFileReader(String fileName)  
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration.LoadFromXmlFile(String fileName)  
at NLog.Config.XmlLoggingConfiguration..ctor(String fileName, LogFactory logFactory)  
at  NLog.Web.SetupBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings>b__2(ISetupLoadConfigurationBuilder config)  
at NLog.SetupBuilderExtensions.LoadConfiguration(ISetupBuilder setupBuilder, Action`1 configBuilder)  
at NLog.Web.SetupBuilderExtensions.LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings(ISetupBuilder setupBuilder, String basePath, String environment, String nlogConfigSection, Boolean optional, Boolean reloadOnChange)  
at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in Z:\rwells\very\special\Program.cs:line 20

nlog-internal.txt
2024-11-20 15:28:06.7547 Debug No file exists at candidate config file location: \\?\UNC\rwells\very\special\bin\Development\net9.0\IDService.exe.nlog
2024-11-20 15:28:06.7547 Debug No file exists at candidate config file location: \\?\UNC\rwells\very\special\bin\Development\net9.0\IDService.dll.nlog
2024-11-20 15:28:06.7779 Debug Reading config from XML file: \\?\UNC\rwells\very\special\bin\Development\net9.0\NLog.config
2024-11-20 15:28:06.8262 Error Failed loading from config file location: \\?\UNC\rwells\very\special\bin\Development\net9.0\NLog.config Exception: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, String relativeUri)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri)
   at NLog.Internal.Fakeables.AppEnvironmentWrapper.LoadXmlFile(String path)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationFileLoader.LoadXmlLoggingConfigurationFile(LogFactory logFactory, String configFile)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfigurationFileLoader.TryLoadLoggingConfiguration(LogFactory logFactory, String configFile, LoggingConfiguration& config)
2024-11-20 15:28:06.8446 Debug No file exists at candidate config file location: \\?\UNC\rwells\very\special\bin\Development\net9.0\NLog.dll.nlog
2024-11-20 15:28:06.8465 Info NLog Configuration has not been loaded.
2024-11-20 15:28:07.3532 Debug No file exists at candidate config file location: \\?\UNC\rwells\very\special\bin\Development\net9.0\nlog.Development.config

uri-hacking.ps1
$paths = (
    '\\sharepoint.business.com\DavWWWRoot\rs\project 1\document.txt',
    'Z:\rwells\very\special\place',
    '\\actual-hostname\actual-sharename\rwells\very\special\place',
    '\\?\UNC\actual-hostname\actual-sharename\rwells\very\special\place'
)

foreach ($path in $paths) {

    echo "$path ->"
    $uri = [System.Uri]$path
    echo "    $($uri.AbsoluteUri) [is UNC = $($uri.IsUnc)]"

}

output on Window Server 2022
\\sharepoint.business.com\DavWWWRoot\rs\project 1\document.txt ->
    file://sharepoint.business.com/DavWWWRoot/rs/project%201/document.txt [is UNC = True]
Z:\rwells\very\special\place ->
    file:///Z:/rwells/very/special/place [is UNC = False]
\\actual-hostname\actual-sharename\rwells\very\special\place ->
    file://actual-hostname/actual-sharename/rwells/very/special/place [is UNC = True]
\\?\UNC\actual-hostname\actual-sharename\rwells\very\special\place ->
InvalidArgument: Z:\rwells\Temp\uri-hacking.ps1:11
Line |
  11 |      $uri = [System.Uri]$path
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot convert value "\\?\UNC\actual-hostname\actual-sharename\rwells\very\special\place" to type "System.Uri". Error: "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."
    file://actual-hostname/actual-sharename/rwells/very/special/place [is UNC = True]


Can you enable NLog InternalLogger from code before calling NLog.LogManager.Setup() ? And then update your question to also include the output from NLog InternalLogger using LogLevel  = Debug ?

@RolfKristensen: Neat trick, thanks. (I, of course, wasn't seeing anything in nlog-internal.txt because this exception was thrown before my nlog.config directives for internal logging were parsed. I'll edit the base question with the result.

\\?\UNC\rwells\very\special\bin\Development\net9.0\NLog.config is a very strange FilePath. What is the output from System.Environment.CurrentDirectory and output from System.AppContext.BaseDirectory ? Maybe some new kind of network-file-share protection?

Interesting, seems it tries to use UNC-file-share-path: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36196538/193178 (Instead of the network-drive), and UNC doesn't seem to be a valid Uri-value.

Here are the values of those properties:
2024-11-21 09:09:17.4953 Debug System.Environment.CurrentDirectory: G:\rwells\very\special 2024-11-21 09:09:17.4953 Debug System.AppContext.BaseDirectory: \\?\UNC\actual-hostname\actual-sharename\rwells\very\special\bin\Development\net9.0\
Notes:

You probably figured out that I masked the real path with rwells\very\special.
In this case, the UNC  in System.AppContext.BaseDirectory doesn't start with rwells..., as it did before. Real hostname and sharename (also masked), show as first 2 path items after UNC.


Aha: \?\UNC prefix is part of the "Long UNC" format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention. I guess it's a valid value but whatever you're passing it to doesn't recognize this.

More from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-file-namespaces: "For file I/O, the "\?" prefix to a path string tells the Windows APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it straight to the file system. For example, if the file system supports large paths and file names, you can exceed the MAX_PATH limits that are otherwise enforced by the Windows APIs."

And [System.Uri] simply doesn't support this UNC syntax. I'll add a PS1 script and its output to the base posting.

Also, it's not clear why System.AppContext.BaseDirectory is returning a Long UNC. The real, normal UNC path (even changing the host name to FQDN, which I'm not actually using in the mapping) is 127 characters, nowhere near the 260 limit of old.

I just reverted TargetFramework to net8.0 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi back to 8.0.11.
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory didn't change but System.AppContext.BaseDirectory did: it now shows Z:\rwells\very\special\bin\Development\net8.0\.
So .NET 9 has changed the behavior of System.AppContext.BaseDirectory.

Thank you for all these excellent observations. Can you see what is the output when using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory with NET9 ?

Rolf, you're welcome! And thank you for the excellent work on NLog, all around. I'll get the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory for you today. Separately, I think I've come across another issue when trying to use SlowCheetah to override (e.g.) minLogLevel for specific target on a Development build. Even with the .15 release it will fail on parsing the long UNC--though not throwing an exception--but on fallback, the file that is found is not mapped path to .\bin\Development\net9.0\NLog.config, but to .\NLog.Development.config. Let me know if you want more details on that.

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory returns the same long UNC that System.AppContext.BaseDirectory does.

Thank you for the investigation. Not sure why NET9 have changed file-path-format. Happy to hear NLog.Web.AspNetCore v5.3.15 have reduced your pain. Think StackOverflow is not the best platform for bug-reports and feature-requests for the NLog-project. Maybe create GitHub issue if you see unexpected behavior when using NLog with NET9.

Thanks, Rolf, will do! (Whatever page I was on when I started researching this issue led me here. In future I'll post to Github, instead.)
